# Compute eigenvector matrices

Tags: python, eigenvector

I have one problem in computing eigenvector matrices.I compute one in python and one online but they have different solution.
Here i use online named matrixcalc, and it's solution:

[image]

and here I use python:

[image]

Can you tell me why they different? Thanks

Comment: There are infinitely many eigenvectors for any eigenvalue. The Python one is normalized to be a unit vector.

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning that it is the COLUMNS of that “E-vector” matrix that are normalised eigenvectors, not the rows (as might at first sight be inferred from the output format).